# Android Facebook SDK Invalid access token after authorization

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-fql

I'm trying to get friend list of users in my Android app. To do so I'm using:**facebook-android-sdk-3.0.1**.

The SDK comes with it's own **loging/logout button** so I used it. When I click login it handles the event(calls login screen asks for permission) so I have nothing to do. Right after login, **onSessionStateChange** function being called which is inside the **A_class extends Fragment**

```
private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        if (state.isOpened()) {             // Session open
            getFriends();                   // Call FQL codes...
        } else if (state.isClosed()) {      // Session closed
            // After first login, It always coming here.Couse:Invalid access token.
        }
    }
```

I've followed the tutorials. I was able to: **login > ask basic permissions > fetch the friend list(by using FQL) > logout**.

After the first successfull login and authentication, If I Logout/Exit from the app, I'm not able to login again. In SDK's **finishAuthorization** it returns **Invalid access token exception**, which fails the session to open.

If I login my facebook account on browser and deauthorize the facebook application on my account, I'm able to login again and fetch friends. It looks like I have to refresh the access token or something... Thank you for any suggestions.

I've figguredout that the token is returning empty string "".

Answer (score 0):

Do you try to re-authorize after logout ? Maybe the token expires. In my apps, I dont do a logout. The token is valid, till it expires. So in that case I login again :).

Comment: Well the token is not expires... But it returns as ""(Empty string) on second try... Can you explain how to re-authorize. I've failed to do that.

Comment: Here is really good sample/project which explains the most functionalities of facebook, included the handling of the token ;). Check this out: Hackbook - [https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/tree/master/samples/Hackbook]

Answer (score 0):

I can't say what the fix is to your exact issue but I remember having a similar problem with FB where the token existed but was invalid.

Basically what happens in the sdk, if I remember correctly, is this

FB auth -> have token? -> yes -> create session with token

As you can see in the above there is no step to check if the token is valid so it's always returning a session that has been closed.

You should try to forcefully flush the token from memory on logout thus avoiding the FB sdk giving you a Session with an invalid token.

The above is just a guess so take it with a pinch of salt.

Answer (score 0):

First check the availability of your access token from Facebook debug tool  from Here https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/access_token. This tool will provide you with some info about the access token provided like `Time to Expire` and `Scopes` ... etc

If the token is expired you have to refresh it (re-authorize it) using the graph api:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=fb_exchange_token&client_id=app-id&client_secret=app-secret&fb_exchange_token=old_token
```

Just replace `old_token` in the URL with the expired access token and use your `app_id` and `secret` instead of `client_id` and `client_secret` respectively. The return value is a new token that you can use instead of the old one.

You can refresh the access token at the time you got the exception of invalid access token and replace it before logging in.